# Creating a (simple) flash game website with rating system

Tags: php, mysql

He guys,

For school I need to make a website where you can play flash games,
rate games by leaving reactions in a text form and a vote system which uses a number system (i.e. 1 = extremely bad and 10 = very good.).

Right now what I want to do is this:

Have an index page for each category of games where users can click on a games name and be directed to another page where the script loads the game.

So far I've written this code for the index (master) page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php
        include("dbconnect.php");
    ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Master page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            //Place all data from this mySQL query in $result.
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gamesDB");

            //While a row of data exists, put that row in $data as an associative array.
            while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                //Echo a link to all the games in the MySQL database.
                echo "<a href='detail.php?id=" . $data['ID'] . "'>";

                    //Echo the games name in the url.
                    echo $data['Spel'];

                //Echo the closing tags
                echo "</a>";
                echo "<br />";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is for the game (detail) page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php
        include("dbconnect.php");
    ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Detail page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            //Place all data out of the database, with the ID number retrieved out of the url into $result.
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gamesDB WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'");

            //While a row of data exists, put that row in $data as an associative array.
            while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                //Retrieve the files name from the database and place it in the <embed> tags as src="...".
                echo "<embed width='800' height='512' src='" . $data['file'] . "' type='application/x-shockwave-flash'></embed>";

                //Echo the games name
                echo "Spel: " . $data['Spel'] . "<br />";

                //Echo the points (not yet functional)
                echo "Punten: " . $data['Punten'] . "<br />";

                //Echo all reactions from users regarding this game.
                echo "Reacties: " . $data['Reactie'] . "<br />";

            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click on the link in the masterpage I get redirected to the detail page but unfortunately, the game does not load.

In my MySQL DB I added the file name to the first row with ID 1. I thought, when I inquire for the filename in the  tags it would load the game but it says (when I right click the box in which the game should display) "Movie not loaded...".

Can anybody help me get this to work ? Is my thinking way off perhaps, or am I headed in the right direction.

Since it is an assignment for school, there is no need to worry about any SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they will be removed from PHP in future versions and your code will stop working then. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: What school is still teaching Flash? ;)

Comment: The above comment is correct, except in that your teacher MAY still be teaching with that code-set.  If that's the case, you should argue with your teacher later.  But for now, if you want a good grade, you'll have to stick with what you're taught.

Comment: Check the generated HTML code, make sure that the path to the flash files is correct.

Comment: Also, just because it is for school doesn't mean you shouldn't worry about SQL injection.  Honestly if I was the instructor, I would consider that strongly in my grading. It is SO easy to address using `prepare()` (prepared statment) methods in Mysqli or PDO. Honestly, that is the way it should be taught.

Comment: Thanks Gerald!
And Mike I am not learning Flash at all, don't know why you thought that ? But it's about PHP :P Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: The file  is located in "USBWebserver v8.6\root\Flash game website". When I check the source code the filename isn't displayed in the embed tags. I get this:

 <embed width='800' height='512' src='' type='application/x-shockwave-flash'></embed>

Comment: It seems to me as if $data['file'] doesn't have any value. Are you sure that 'file' is the name of the column for the filename of the flash?

Comment: Somehow it actually wasn't .... Thanks for your comment @Jujunol
It's working now!

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I'm gonne look into msqli and PDO and see if I can figure out how it works. I hope it is somewhat simmelar.

Comment: Why do I receive Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->'  when I use the mysqli->query() ?

Comment: Never mind! Fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually forgot to put an entry into the file column.
Now that the problem I had with `"<embed>"` has been resolved, I would like to focus on how to add user comments to my 'comments' column, and have each comment displayed. I'd like to find the code myself as much as possible so you could just react to my question with pointers instead of writing the complete code I would be very grateful.